# Invalid User ID Specified When Trying to Remove Message

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

This is my first time to use Apps Scripts. I am only using this on my personal email account. I am trying to use a script that I came across on StackOverflow that is supposed to permanently delete emails with specific words that are in my spam folder. I have tested the code and it seems to correctly find the emails based on the text that I specify.

My problem is that I cannot get it perform the actual deletion of the emails. I think that I am not specifying my email address correctly. In my code example, I used **me**. I have also tried hard coding my email, but that did not work.

When I try to execute the code, it gives me the following error: "**GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to gmail.users.messages.delete failed with error: Invalid user id specified in request/Delegation denied at deleteForever(Code:17:29)**

What is the proper way to reference my personal email account?

```
function setTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('deleteForever')
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create()
}

function deleteForever() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:spam");

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    console.log(i)
    if (msg.getPlainBody().match(/truck|car|(you won)/gi) !== null){
        console.log('Found It!')
       Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, threads[i].getId.toString()); 
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the Gmail API.  Is your project a Cloud Platform Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SUGGESTION

Based on your code, here are the problems:

1. You are using **me** in your `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove()` as a variable that is non-existing, thus causing the `Invalid user id` error.
2. You also need to use the `message` ID instead of the `threads[i]` ID as required on the `id` parameter of the [users.messages.delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/delete#path-parameters) method.

### Tweaked Script

```
function deleteForever() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:spam");

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    console.log(i)
    if (msg.getPlainBody().match(/truck|car|(you won)/gi) !== null){
        console.log('Found It!')
       Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', msg.getId()); 
    }

  }
}
```

### Demo

After running the script:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

In your script, the variable `me` is `undefined`. And `undefined` is not a valid "userId". `me` should be the string `"me"`.

```
Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", threads[i].getId.toString());
```